# Calling foldLeft on Buffer from Java

Tags: scala

I want to call the `foldLeft` method on a scala `Buffer`, from Java code:

```
    List<Integer> javaList = new ArrayList<>();
    javaList.add(1);
    javaList.add(3);
    javaList.add(5);

    Buffer<Integer> scalaBuffer = JavaConversions.asScalaBuffer(javaList);

    scalaBuffer.foldLeft(0, new Function2<Integer, Integer, Integer>() {
        @Override
        public Integer apply(Integer accumulator, Integer element) {
            return carry + element;
        }
    });
```

But I get the following compiler error:

```
Multiple markers at this line
- The type new Function2<Integer,Integer,Integer>(){} must implement the 
 inherited abstract method Function2<Integer,Integer,Integer>.apply$mcVDI
 $sp(double, int)
- The type new Function2<Integer,Integer,Integer>(){} must implement the 
 inherited abstract method Function2<Integer,Integer,Integer>.tupled$mcIDD$sp()
- The type new Function2<Integer,Integer,Integer>(){} must implement the 
 inherited abstract method Function2<Integer,Integer,Integer>.tupled$mcVJJ$sp()
- The type new Function2<Integer,Integer,Integer>(){} must implement the 
 inherited abstract method Function2<Integer,Integer,Integer>.apply$mcZDJ
 $sp(double, long)
    .
    .
    .
```

Basically, I have to implement a whole load of methods that don't interest me.

Is there an easy solution to calling the foldLeft method on a monad, from Java?

Thanks,
John

(Using Scala 2.10-M5 and JDK 1.7)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this scala-lang thread](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/10551), the appropriate course of action is probably to extend `scala.runtime.AbstractFunction2` instead of directly implementing `Function2`.

That thread is a bit old in scala time, but it may point toward a solution.  I confess I haven't tried it myself.

Comment: You win.  Both answers are correct. Yours has a packagename and a link so its slightly better.

Answer (score 1):

You could try extending `AbstractFunction2`, rather than implementing `Function2`.

For the java compiler, scala traits are only interfaces, and there is no way it will automatically get you the implementation of those methods that are not abstract in the trait. Looking only at the interfaces, all the methods are abstract as seen from java.